# How to stop Bump / Flickering of a WebAR scene in three.js

Tags: three.js, aruco

As an example, I tried to set up an AR scene in three.js.

I use "aruco.js" to do that. When I load obj or any other models everything works great, However when the marker is placed in front of the camera it gets detected and the scene flickers/bumps violently. Any serious reason why this is happening?

As live demo would be hard to set up, I just uploaded a video on YouTube to illustrate my point: https://youtu.be/9jMso7vmw1M

**So my exact question is: what is the best way to make AR scene stick to the marker without any flicker?**

Code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6cw3ta57/

```
var markerObject3D = new THREE.Object3D()
scene.add(markerObject3D)
  // set the markerObject3D as visible
markerObject3D.visible = false
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //        code in jsfiddle
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't work btw.

Comment: @msun please check the updated question.

Comment: Hey that's really cool! I'll check out aruco.js. Anyway, I'm not sure this is an issue with three.js per se. Based on your code, in lieu of tweaking the aruco.js settings to be more sensitive/accurate, it seems the simplest fix might be to add a lifespan/delay to the markerObject3D to prevent it from being hidden too often -- and continuously refresh that lifespan/delay whenever the marker is detected.

Comment: @msun, thanks for the reply, Please do let me know if it works, i'm trying on the same lines as you suggested.

Comment: @msun I just added this time out function, the result seems to be okay, but is there any other way to fine tune the flicker ?

onRenderFcts.forEach(function(onRenderFct){
    setTimeout(function(){
   onRenderFct(now, now - previousTime)
  })
  previousTime = now
  },80000);
 })